# finding solution for Bin packing problem using bitmasking under smaller constraints

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, bitmask

We have n box and an array of weights, where weight of ith box is given by arr[i]. We have a container which can carry a maximum weight of w. Now we have to find minimum number of containers required to pack these N items.

> Exact question link : - https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/coding-round-practice/challenges/michaels-worries
>
> Useful Resources :-
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/

If the constraints are small, we can solve this problem using Dynamic programming with bitmasking. Here is a code which i wrote to implement the same. However it is giving Time limit exceeded.

> Constraints:
>
> 1 <= n <= 20
>
> 1 <= w <= 10^9
>
> 0 <= arr[i] <= w

```
int get_minimum_parcels(int n, int w, vector<int> arr) {
    //stores the weight of boxes for every possible combination
    vector<int> sums(1<<n); 
    for(int i=0;i<(1<<n);i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i & (1<<j)){
                sums[i]+=arr[j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    // dp[i][j] denotes whether it is possible to distribute
    // the boxes as mentioned in the j bitmask to i containers 
    vector<vector<bool> > dp(21,vector<bool> (1<<n));

    // Initialising for 1 container
    for(int i=0;i<(1<<n);i++){
        if(sums[i]<=w){
            dp[1][i]=true;
        } else{
            dp[1][i]=false;
        }
    }
    
    // The maximum answer n is always possible,
    // Thus checking from 2 to n to find the min possible answer 
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<(1<<n);j++){
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            // Enumerating the submasks
            for(int k=j;k;k = (k-1) & j){
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j] | (sums[k]<=w && dp[i-1][j-k]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(dp[i][(1<<n)-1])
           return i;
    }

    return n;
}
```

**Can we optimize this solution?**